# Laravel for loop error

Tags: php, laravel

When I receive a number in my controller and pass it to the view like this:

```
public function show(Request $request)
{
    $products = $request->products;
    return view('admin.administration')->with('products',$products);
}
```

And show it in my view like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
                        @for($i=0; $i <{{ $products }}; $i++)
                            <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="rol" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Product:</label>
                               <div class="col-lg-10">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title>" placeholder="Titel" name="title>">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description>" placeholder="Beschrijving" name="description>">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price>" placeholder="prijs" name="price">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="number>" placeholder="Aantal" name="number">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="total>" placeholder="Totaal" name="total">
                                </div>
                             </div>
                        @endfor
                    </div>
```

It throws the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' (View:
>   /home/vagrant/Code/l/resources/views/admin/administration.blade.php)

Checked with a dd but the value isn't empty. When I replace {{ $products }} with for example 5 it works. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing

```
@for($i=0; $i < {{ $products}}; $i++)
```

with

```
@for($i=0; $i < $products; $i++)
```

`{{$products}}` is shorthand for `<?php echo $products; ?>`